# Dry Ice in Liquid States

Tags: thermodynamics, states-of-matter

If I melt the dry ice in a pool.
I am thinking that Can I have bath without getting wet by melted dry ice?

Comment: How are you defining wet? is 'wet' to you covered in water, or just any liquid? If youre using the water idea of wet then its impossibble to get wet from dry ice in liquid form because its chemical composition is not H20

Comment: I dont understand what you are asking.

Comment: If you want to get a bath and not get wet... that bath would be the last one you'd try.

Answer (score 4):

> Are you ready to jump into a pool with pressure of about $50\times 10^5pa$ ??

Yes, $P_c$, critical pressure of carbon-di-oxide is about $5.1\  atm$, that too at about  $-50^0 C$. So, a pool with liquid $CO_2$ will never be opened for a bath!

Also at room temperature this will go above $50atm!!$

[image]

[This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TA8zIl10-Z8) would happen if you try turning it into liquid.

Also If we consider your question as :Will liquid $CO_2$ wet any surface? Then answer would be *probably* `yes`.That is probably visible in vedio as well. Liquid $CO_2$ has a low [surface tension](http://www.ddbst.com/en/EED/PCP/SFT_C1050.php).

Comment: Ok I do not think to jump into it anymore.
what about showerhead? Can I use them with it?
Can we mix it with air and decrease under 50atm at room temp.?
Just think about it, get shower still dry.
It could be cool, couldn't it? :P

Comment: @Johnsimit I answered it also. Surface tension is very low and so it will wet any surface in contact